Do you accept questions about stochastic cellular automata and stochastic languages related to Kolmogorov theorem?
I don't see any questions about this topic on your site.

Perhaps [cs.se], [stats.se], or [math.se] would be an option? I am not familiar with these automata and am not active on any of those sites, but it seems they may be relevant.

This site is about the study of natural human languages. Perhaps you could study human languages using the things you mentioned, but questions simply about them and not about human languages would be off-topic.

Yes, with an asterisk.
This site isn't about the study of "languages" as used in computer science (i.e. a potentially infinite set of strings), per se; it's about the study of natural languages used by humans to communicate.
But, the one often can be applied to the other. Regular expressions and finite state transducers, for example, are often used to model phonology and morphology.
So, we accept questions about these topics, as long as they're connected to the study of natural human languages. For anything else, CS.se will be better.
